# Need a formula to sort Excel column by

Tags: math, excel-formula, formula, formulas

Please have a look at this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zdUYp0bUavXm4BpiTJ_Wt7Dy403hTvCxZQm6mJu3628/edit#gid=0)

I need a formula that would put the green rows at the top or near the top at least and the red rows at or near the bottom the column is sorted. It doesn't have to work for any numbers, just the ones in this spreadsheet

I got close with by sorting by column D which has `(columnA / columnB * 100) * columnA` but there are green outlier rows in the middle that should be more towards the top area

Comment: what is determining the colors?

Comment: @DavidLee The red rows represent small ratios and small numbers that produce big ratios that unrepresentivie because they're only big because the numbers are small. eg. person A shares 1 thing with person B so they have 100% in common but they only have 100% because they only had one thing to begin with. where is a person C with 300  and person D with 500 have only 60% in common even though they have 300 things in common. so they get out ranked by A-B even though A-B have way less in common. I hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You say nothing about the line colored tan (near-red), so I treat that as a red line.

Put a new formula in E2,

```
=IF(A2<5,100,0)+IF(C2>0.68,0,10)-D2/10000
```

then copy it down column Sort the table on column E, increasing. You then get this:

[image]

This works because the green rows are distinguished in their column C, which is 0.667 or less for green and 0.700 for all other rows. The red rows are distinguished in their column A, which is 2 or less for red (and for the tan) and 7 or more for all other rows. So my formula makes breakpoints at 5 for column A and 0.68 for column C and assigns appropriate numbers, adding them for a final score. I use column D as a tie-breaker, as in your original data. You can remove the `-D2/10000` if you don't care about tie-breakers in each color section.

I did all this in Microsoft Excel (in Office 365), as in your question title.